# USB flash drive cannot be read only on a specific computer

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a SanDisk Cruzer 32gb flash drive that cannot be read only on a specific computer due to some unknown reason. Do note that **all my other flash drives are working fine on this computer**. Here's my situation...

## Background Info

I recently bought a HP laptop. Before wiping the laptop's hard disk, I used HP recovery media creator to store the HP recovery image in my flash drive. After I was done with wiping my laptop's hard disk and making sure my clean installation of the operating system works, **I wiped my flash drive with the standard Windows formatting utility**. I don't like the OEM's recovery stuffs because of all the bloatware, but I backed it up to my flash drive just in case my clean installation fails.

## The Problem

Now, this flash drive **cannot be read on my main desktop** (running Windows 8) anymore. However, the same flash drive **can be read on my other two computers** (also running Windows 8) perfectly fine.

### Observations:

- The flash drive cannot be accessed in Windows Explorer or any Explorer alternatives.
- Received *"Windows can't access this disk"* error messages when trying to check the disk's filesystem.
- The flash drive's size cannot be viewed in My Computer.

Ironically, according to the Device Manager, the USB flash drive is detected and working fine.

### Things I've Tried

- Uninstalling the USB mass storage driver and rebooting.
- Uninstalling all USB drivers and rebooting.
- Wiping and reformatting my flash drive on the computers that it can work on using MiniTool Partition Wizard.
- Using BootIce to rewrite the MBR of the flash drive.
- Copying the MBR of my other flash drives to the problem flash drive using BootIce.
- I've also tried formatting in FAT16, FAT32 and NTFS.

**All of the above methods have failed.** Does anyone know what's the problem, or have encountered such errors before? Please enlighten me. Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you. =)

Comment: What shows in the Disk Manager? What do you mean by "trying to check the disk's filesystem"?

Comment: The flash drive shows up in Disk Management with no partitions. And I meant you can check the disk's filesystem using the Windows built-in tool under Properties > Tools > Error-checking.

Do note, MiniTool Partition Wizard's surface test in another computer works fine with no errors. And the partition shows up in other computers as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue before and this is what i did to resolve.

Open Device Manager and then plug in the drive.

- Device Manager was blinking when the drive was plugged in, so something was recognizing it.  However, no additional disk device was appearing.
- Looking in the "Universal Serial Bus Controllers" section in Device Manager, there was a "Mass Storage" driver loaded.  Other USB drives when plugged in would load a "USB Mass Storage Device" driver for a moment before that disappearing and the additional disk device then appearing.
- I right clicked and uninstalled the apparently erroneously loaded/associated/cached "Mass Storage" driver.  When the drive was reconnected the proper "USB Mass Storage Device" driver then loaded and it started working again.

I think the cause of it was removing the device while Windows was still loading the drivers for it.  Sometimes Windows takes a while to fully recognize a device (USB devices can have "subdevices" which require a chain of drivers to be scanned/loaded) and if this process is interrupted it may remember the wrong driver for the device.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10.  I had to 'Uninstall the device' and then unplug and replug it in.  Finally my USB stick appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact issue but never got it resolved; The work around (as I was not able to fix it) was to copy the data to another flash drive!

Comment: Did you use HP recovery media creator as well? I think it did something to the first few sectors of the flash drive.

Comment: Actually, no. I did nothing clever with it, other than buy it from a shop, put on a few music files from another machine and then tried to read it from my machine and no luck; I guess it could be how the drive was formatted but, nothing I tried worked sadly (hence my work around). Sorry I didn't have a 'real' solution to help.